# Mysql-client without server

Tags: mysql

I just installed the MySQL-client-5.5.24-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.

I'm trying to connect to a database on a different machine but when I run "mysql" I get an error:

```
$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Any idea how to run the mysql client (without the server running)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the host:

```
mysql -h host ...
```

See `man mysql` for all options.

Answer (score 4):

You didnt tell it where to connect to. You need to use '-h host' or '-h server.ip.add.ress'

```
 mysql -h host -u <username>
```

(and add -p if you have password set up)

Answer (score 3):

Use different commandline options to specify the remote MySQL server you want to connect to.

`-h servername`

`-u username`

E.g. `mysql -h server.example.com -u username -p database`

`-p` specifies that you will enter your password from the commandline right after connecting to MySQL.

You can also add your options in a configuration file.

**~/.my.cnf**

```
[client]
user = dbuser
pass = dbpass
host = mysql.example.com
default-character-set = utf8
```

And then connect to MySQL with the following command:

`mysql`

Or to a specific database:

`mysql <database>`

Comment: If you call your file `.my.cnf` you won't need `--defaults-extra-file=~/.mysql-client.cf`.

Comment: Good call, I have many mysql-servers I connect from so I normally use the `--defaults-extra-file` options.